# Topic requests are not important enough to be deserving of repuation

Tags: feature-request, documentation

When a topic request is fulfilled, the person who requested it gets rep. That has led to people flooding the system with lots of crappy topic requests that already exists. And it takes longer to dismiss them (since you have to link to the topic/example that covers it) than to write new ones.

We need to remove the incentive for this.